# Doc4j pptx find and replace table row

Tags: java, powerpoint, docx4j

I have a requirement where I need to replace some text in a Powerpoint File at runtime(Powerpoint file is being used as a template with some placeholders/tokes e.g. `{{data1}}` ) in one row on table.

I referred to the other links on the forum and started with 'docx4j' but am not able to go beyond a point and the documentation is not very clear

```
    List tableCells = clonedRow.getTc();
    // Finally, insert the copy in the list
    theTable.getTr().add(clonedRow); // standard Java list API
     for (int ix = 0; ix < tableCells.size(); ix++)
     {
         CTTableCell  tableCell = (CTTableCell)XmlUtils.unwrap(tableCells.get(ix));
        // List<CTTextParagraph> value=tableCell.getTxBody().getP();

         for (CTTextParagraph p : tableCell.getTxBody().getP()) {
             Text text = (Text) ((JAXBElement) p).getValue();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SlidePart extends JaxbXmlPart, which contains:

```
public void variableReplace(java.util.Map<String, String> mappings)
```

If you want to use variableReplace, your variables should be appear like so: ${key1}, ${key2}

For an example, see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/VariableReplace.java  That's for a docx; you just need to apply it to your SlidePart.

Comment: thanks for your help. variable replace does not satisfy in my case. before find and replace operations in one row on table. have to validated content is present  or not. like this scenario done in word using Docx4j example  for (int j=0;j<table.size();j++) {
    Text text = (Text) table.get(j);
    String textValueBefore = text.getValue();
    String replacementValue = textToAdd.get(i).get(textValueBefore);
    if(replacementValue != null)) {
     text.setValue(replacementValue);
    
    }          dont know how to do same as in ppt using Docx4j